# Why is the ResultSet not same for insert and select queries

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, datastax-java-driver

When I use `session.execute` in `cassandra`, I notice that the `ResultSet`'s structure is different for the same table. If I am querying the table to get a record using `Where`, the `ResultSet` contains the data fetched from the table.

```java
val resultSet = session.execute(whereClause)
```

gives

```java
ResultSet[ exhausted: false, Columns[year(bigint), month(bigint), 
    creation_time_hour(bigint), creation_time_minute(bigint), 
    question_id(uuid), question_description(varchar)]]
```

But if I use `Insert`, I get something totally different.

```java
ResultSet[ exhausted: false, Columns[[applied](boolean)]]
```

Is this expected behavior? Is there a way to get the data "inserted" by `cassandra` in the table in the `ResultSet` returned by `execute` method?

Comment: I don't no anything about Cassandra but an Sql Insert doesn't return anything. There  are things you can retrieve after an insert for some DBMS like number of rows inserted and the generated PK if the table has one but not the actual data inserted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, the `INSERT` doesn't return the inserted values back to user. The exception is insert that triggers lightweight transaction - if you use `IF NOT EXISTS`. In this case, it may return:

1. single row with single column `[applied]` with `true` value - this means that data were inserted;

```
cqlsh:test> insert into test.u2(id,u) values(5, {id:1, t1:3}) if not exists;

 [applied]
-----------
      True
```

2. single row with all values of the corresponding row of the table, plus column `[applied]` with `false` value - this happens when row with given primary key already exists.

```
cqlsh:test> insert into test.u2(id,u) values(1, {id:1, t1:2});
cqlsh:test> insert into test.u2(id,u) values(1, {id:1, t1:3}) if not exists;

 [applied] | id | u
-----------+----+----------------
     False |  1 | {id: 1, t1: 2}
```

Comment: So the answer is no, you can't get the inserted data returned when doing an insert.